# Protractor not finding an element in angular 6 app

Tags: angular, protractor

content in project.po.ts ->

```
newProjectButton() {
  return element(by.id('new-project'));
}

newProjectButtonText() {
  return this.newProjectButton().getText();
}
```

contents in spec file ->

```
describe('Projects', function () {
 let page: RMLProjectsPage;
 page = new RMLProjectsPage();  

 it('should create new project and its first workspace', () => {

   page.navigateToProjectsPage();

   expect(page.newProjectButtonText()).toEqual('New Project');

   ...
```

The test runs and a login test passes prior to this test. However, after it successfully navigates to projects page, it cannot find the new-project button. error is **Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="new-project"])**

Now if I put browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; after page construction , it finds that button, but it makes other query in a reactive form to fail. In an angular app we should not do browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; right? What am I missing here ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` is deprectaed try `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);`.

To answer your question, if you make `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);` then you are asking protractor to wait until all the http requests are completed. If your application has a continuous network calls then there `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` comes into picture.

Note: If you are using `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` then you have to using explicit waits.

Hope the answer helps you.

For more info refer https://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts

Comment: `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` combined with `const ec = protractor.ExpectedConditions;browser.wait(ec.elementToBeClickable(page.nextComputeButton()), 5000);` seems to be working ... browser.ignoreSynchronization = true was there so this wait did not work before